# Using  __utm.gif for google analytic to track the open rate

Tags: html, email, google-analytics

I have found the google analytics have actually the gif for me to add in the email,
but i am not sure whether the parameter setting is apporpriate

I follow some suggestion on internet, the only parameter required is

```
Parameter    Description
utmac        Google Analytics account ID
utmn         Random ID to prevent the browser from caching the returned image
utmp         Relative path of the page to be tracked
utmr         Complete referral URL
```

and the paratmer suggested on google

```
Campaign Source (utm_source)

Campaign Medium (utm_medium)    

Campaign Name (utm_campaign)
```

to create a gif

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmac=UA-29940706-1&utmn=1214284135&utmp=receipent-email@hotmail.com&utmr=0?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=newsletter1
```

The problem are:

1. Whether the gif parameter correct?
2. Is it takes a day before the actual tracking generate on the google analytic website?
3. The way to do this is change the Campaign Name (utm_campaign) for other campaign, if the user want to track the result, just add the gif into the email, that's all?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important parameter is `utmcc` that contain Analytics cookies values, and especially the `__utma` cookie value that contain visitor/session informations :

```
__utma=<domain_hash>.<session_id>.<first_time>.<last_time>.<current_time>.<session_count>
```

Note : please avoid to push personals datas like email into Analytics.

**EDIT:**

Don't forget that the majority of email client DO NOT load image by default. So you will not obtain accurate statistics.

Comment: http://www.kontain.com/karlstanton/entries/47993/tracking-your-email-campaigns/   Is this link can help me achieve check the open rate?

Comment: Since it's a static email, how do you set last_time/current_time to useful values?